# is there any way to pass VM arguments for my Android app?

Tags: android, jvm, jvm-arguments

Official Android Application Fundamentals says,
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals

> Each process has its own virtual machine (VM), so an app's code runs in isolation from other apps.

If my app is one of the unique processes that runs on the Android OS and is allowed to have its own VM instance, is there any way I can provide VM arguments to my app specific instance of VM when the user launches the app?

Update(around two months later):
or may be I stupidly mistook this each-VM-for-one-Android-process stuff as the JVM instance because the former kind of VM is about a type of container not the JVM?